# Generate Multiple Tables From A Single Map React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to generate six different React bootstrap tables based on the `groupName` field of the below data (more objects inside, just used three for example):

`CompetitionData.js`

```
const data= {
    "players": [],
    "teams": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "England",
            "groupName": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Germany",
            "groupName": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Russia",
            "groupName": 2
        }
    ]
}

export default data;
```

Currently I'm able to map through the data and generate a single table, but not sure how to loop through the data just once in order to generate six different tables...

`Standings.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import CompetitionData from "../data/CompetitionData";

export const Standings = () => {
  const data = CompetitionData;

  return (
      <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" variant ="dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>Group</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data?.teams?.length
            ? data.teams.map((team, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{team.name}</td>
                  <td>{team.groupName}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            : null}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
  );
};
```

Any idea how to go about doing that?